# How to create EC2 instance with EBS volume in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Hi I am trying to create an Amazon EC2 instance with an EBS volume. I have created a CloudFormation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "First EC2 instance"
Resources:
 FirstLinuxEC2instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: 'ap-southeast-2a'
      ImageId: 'ami-0c1d8842b9bfc767c'
      InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: 'terminate'
      InstanceType: 't2.micro'
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - 'sg-79862305'
      Volumes:
        Device: "/dev/sdf"
        VolumeId: !Ref NewVolume
 NewVolume:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
  Properties:
    Size: 1
    AvailabilityZone: 'ap-southeast-2a'
    Tags:
      - Key: MyTag
        Value: TagValue
  DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
```

When I upload this template I am getting below error.

> Value of property Volumes must be of type List

Can someone help me to figure it out the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Try this!

```
Volumes:
  -
   Device: "/dev/sdf"
   VolumeId: !Ref NewVolume
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes volumes is of type array. So even a single volume needs to be in a pair of square brackets (json). You can try [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) which is an online cloudformation template generator. It is very useful to make it outright clear which property is of what type with inline description.